mongoose find where _id is in an array of objects
I have the following variable in my code:
const data = [
   { _id: "66324310da5f0f7575da0292", from: "66324110da5f0f7275cd8949" }, 
   { _id: "66324350sa5f0sdd575da0s92", from: "62a34303530f3275c3d99" }
]

I want to find all users where their _id is equal to any from value in the data variable. The problem I have is that data is an array of objects, and I want to query based on the from property of all the objects within the array.
I have tried the following code:
User.updateMany({_id: {$in: data})

However, this doesn't work as it isn't specifically checking the from attribute, and data is an array of objects.
Any other ways I can accomplish this? Thanks.

const ids = data.map((entry) => new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(entry.from)); then User.updateMany({_id: {$in: ids}, {...})

A simple Array#map should be enough.
const ids = data.map((entry) => entry.from);

You might need to convert the entry.from value to an ObjectId if it isn't already.
Using the official MongoDB driver that would look like this:
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

const ids = data.map((entry) => ObjectId.createFromHexString(entry.from));

or using Mongoose
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ids = data.map((entry) =>
  mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromHexString(entry.from),
);


You can use the JavaScript map function:
User.updateMany({_id: {$in: data.map((x) => x.from)})

This will create a new list for the query that has only the from attribute from each object.
